# OpenGL fails to render on windows 8

Tags: windows, visual-studio, opengl, windows-8

I am encountering an issue where nothing is rendered when running a simple OpenGL application through VS 2012 on Windows 8.

I had a little debug renderer I was using to prototype some projects and had it up and running on Windows 7 using VS 2012 Express Edition.

I upgraded to Windows 8, and cloned the git repository with my work on. After installing the latest drivers and installing VS 2012, I ran my application, but nothing displayed, all I get is the screen clear colour. I was getting an exception before but that's because I didn't have the right drivers so when calling glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION,...) I'd get -1 as OpenGL wasn't set up correctly. It is initialised correctly now and when stepping through, it looks like everything is working fine, the only problem is I'm not seeing anything.

To make sure it wasn't just my code I downloaded some of the Swiftless OpenGL examples and got the exact same thing. My application was using OpenGL 3.2 and no deprecated functionality. My hardware can support up to 3.3, and if it is of any use I am running Window 8 through Boot Camp on a Macbook air.

I have been bashing my head against a wall for the last couple of days trying to solve this but I'm not having much luck, I thought I'd throw it out there to see if anyone has had a similar problem, I'd be really grateful if anyone can offer any information. If someone with Windows 8 could download and build a simple OpenGL application though VS just to see if they can get something up on screen that would be interesting!

Comment: This almost certainly is a graphics driver issue, and probably doesn't belong on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use the good old and deprecated fixed function pipeline, namely immediate mode draw calls like `glBegin()`, `glVertex*()` and `glEnd()`? If so, try to draw your stuff using vertex arrays. Even if this doesn't help in your specific situation, immediate mode draw calls should be avoided at all cost to make the code forward compatible. The OpenGL 3.x core profile doesn't contain these old API functions anymore. I had also a blank screen on my new Win 7 notebook (OpenGL 3.3) because of some stale immediate mode draw calls (FTGL).

EDIT:

For independent GL debugging, I recommend this:

http://www.gremedy.com/

This program allows you to pause the execution and investigate buffer contents, shader programs and more.

Comment: I am not using anyone of the deprecated functionality, everything OpenGL related is 3.0 or above. I am not using VBOs but I am using vertex arrays for all my drawing. I could try using VBOs perhaps, that potentially might be causing the problem, but it still doesn't explain why it worked fine on Windows 7 and not 8, and the vertex arrays should still work really, you'd hope anyway.

Comment: Client side vertex arrays should not be the cause of the problem. What about shaders? Do you have a program bound during all drawcalls?

Comment: That gremedy debugger looks awesome! Thanks for the link, I will see if I can use that to find out any more. I have two simple shaders, one for transforming verticies with color attributes and one for vertices with tex coords. I bind each shader when I come to use it, that code is the same as before (when I was using Windows 7) and was all working correctly.

Comment: Hang on I think I know what it is, just used the gDebugger tool and it looks as though for some reason the openGL calls are being made from another render context. I'm seeing this debug error printed out: Detected error: The debugged process asked for an extension function pointer (glEnableVertexAttribArray) from one render context, but called this function pointer in another render context (context #2). That must be it, thank you very much for the link on the debugging tool, massive help! Thanks! :)

Comment: Youre welcome! Do you create an initial render context to get function pointers for a GL 3 context, so that you have created 2 in total? I can just guess, so I wish you great success.

Comment: That's right yeah, I create a 2.1 context, initialise glew, then if it is available, I create a new 3.0 context using wglCreateContextAttribsARB, and delete the previous context. Somewhere along the line though the switch must not happen correctly. Again it is odd why this is only happening on a different configuration (windows 8? somehow?), but hopefully I can puzzle it out, I'll let you know what the fix is when I get it working! Thanks again man, I owe you a beer! :)

Comment: Thanks xD. You might already think about just initializing GLEW in the final render context, as extensions and function pointers may change. This could explain, why it worked on Win 7, if there was no significant difference, maybe an older driver. One doesn't need anything but `wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB")` within the first context. Good luck :-)

Comment: Hey man, quick update to this. I spent a while fixing the debug error messages that were showing up in gDebugger and after fixing them all by redefining the glew functions using wglGetProcAddress("..") I still was encountering the same problem, nothing was rendering :( I did some more digging, and decided to try and move my code over to using VBOs instead of client side vertex arrays (just in-case), and low and behold, that fixed it! I am not sure why the client side stuff no longer works, it might be a graphics driver/windows 8 thing, not sure, but they no longer seem to work.

Comment: This is possible, if you're instantiating a core profile context, where these are deprecated (didn't remember). The returned context profile might be the actual difference, which causes your problem. Since nVidia does have some errors in their implementation too, either driver or even both could do something odd. The compatilility flag may have helped there. Of course, replacing everything with VBO's is way better. See this spec http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_create_context.txt , and especially the difference between WGL_ARB_create_context and WGL_ARB_create_context_profile.

Comment: Interesting thanks. Haha yeah I know, I was just being lazy as nothing was performance critical and it was faster/easier to do it the old way when I wrote it. I'm going to see if I can switch the compatibility mode to see if that makes a difference at all, otherwise I'll just update my existing code to use VBOs, thanks again for your help man!

Comment: You're welcome. I learned to RTFM before claiming stuff without seeing the code :-)

Comment: How can _accepted_ anwsers bundled with relevant comments and obvioulsy worth of tens of minutes of research, thinking and writing still have a score of "0"?? :) 

SO is a strange place nowdays.

Answer (score 1):

> After installing the latest drivers

Where did you get the drivers from? Only drivers you download directly from the GPU vendor's website ship with proper OpenGL support. The drivers automatically installed by Windows have only poor OpenGL support.

Comment: I downloaded the latest drivers from NVidia's website. I have a 9400M in my machine and the driver I got was 310.70. It is so weird as it seems like everything should work but nothing displays, I wonder if it is a problem specific to Windows 8. I had no issued on Windows 7 with the same configuration.

Answer (score -1):

opengl support is not available for windows 8.their are still techniques to use it on windows its better to search on google coz i tried for minecraft game [or u can check here too](http://hqtips.com/os/windows/how-to-fix-opengl-error-on-windows-8/)

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"Error 403 - This web app is stopped"*